# Multi state Check box in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, custom-controls, xamarin.mac

I need to implement a check box which can have multiple states, I am new to Xamarin and OSX development. I could not find any built in control that I could use. I guess I need to implement a custom user control, which class should I derive from and how should I approach it?

Comment: can you be more specific in what you need an what is missing in the controls you looked at?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you checked this already, but this might help you : 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/custom-controls/

It's not much as help but it might lead you to something. Hope it will help you at least a little bit. It helped me to start with custom controls as I am in about the same situation as yours, but with different kind of controls needed

Comment: I have already gone through that link, I am still having some issues to get exactly what i need. Thanks for looking it up.

Comment: If you want to diverge from standard macOS behavior, a custom control is the right answer. Deriving from NSControl and drawing everything, as that link suggests is likely your best option.